# Deleting Dynamic Relative layout by the click of button inside the respective layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a dynamic `RelativeLayout` with a `Imageview` inside it. Once the user clicks on that `ImageView`, I would like to change the delete the parent view (`RelativeLayout`). I know I can do this by storing the parent view in a variable, but I'd like to avoid that (I have very good reasons for not wanting this). Isn't there a way to just access the parent view from the `ImageView` itself?

Comment: post your code which you tried

Comment: imageview.getParent();

Answer (score 2):

you can get the parent View by getParent method, some things like this

```
RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) ((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).getParent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

`View view = findViewById(R.id.view);`
`view.removeView(yourView);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both for helping ,here's mine for dynamically created layout.
For Imageview or Button which is also created dynamically, override the onClick function and pass the id or tag to the passing function

```
 private View.OnClickListener HandleOnClick(final ImageView imageView, final int id) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            RelativeLayout yourRelLay= (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();
           // yourRelLay.removeView((View) view.getParent());
            yourRelLay.removeAllViews();
            rll.removeView(yourRelLay);


        }
    };
```